# Cómo identificar qué checkbox ha sido seleccionado

Tags: php, html, formularios, checkbox

Cuando envío este formulario no consigo identificar qué checkbox ha sido seleccionado. Marque el que marque, siempre me indica las posiciones del array empezando desde 0 porque los valores a off simplemente no los envía. ¿Hay alguna solución a este problema?

```
<pre>
    <?php
        print_r($_POST);
    ?>
</pre>

<form method="post">
    0<input type="checkbox" name="campo[]"/>
    1<input type="checkbox" name="campo[]"/>
    2<input type="checkbox" name="campo[]"/>
    <button>Probar</button>
</form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para el caso de la figura, me gustaría recibir:

```
(
    [campo] => Array
        (
            [0] => off
            [1] => off
            [2] => on
        )

)
```

O, incluso:

```
(
    [campo] => Array
        (
            [2] => on
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los `<input type="checkbox">` tienen un comportamiento peculiar, ya que tan solo se envían en caso de estar seleccionados. Pero por lo demás son como un campo cualquiera, enviándose como clave el atributo **name** y como valor el atributo **value**. Por ello, con agregarle un value a tus `<input type="checkbox">` conseguirías que se enviara algo como esto:

**Se envía por POST (seleccionando el segundo y el tercer input)**

```
campo[]: 1
campo[]: 2
```

**Ejemplo:**

```html
<form method="post">
    0<input type="checkbox" name="campo[]" value="0"/>
    1<input type="checkbox" name="campo[]" value="1"/>
    2<input type="checkbox" name="campo[]" value="2"/>
    <button>Probar</button>
</form>
```

De esta manera, al recuperar en tu **backend** `$_POST['campo']` tendrías un array con los values de los checkbox seleccionados.

Comment: Envía el dato del `value` únicamente cuando validas el checkbox e igualmente empezando en el `0`, si no lo validas no envía nada. La verdad es que esa solución hubiera estado genial y, ahora que lo pienso, tal vez pueda resultarme más sencilla de implementar que la mía

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre una, agregar el campo id en el checkbox con eso ya tenemos los resultados independientes:

```
<form method="post">
    0<input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" name="cbox1"/>
    1<input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" name="cbox2"/>
    2<input type="checkbox" id="cbox3" name="cbox3"/>
<button>Probar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Efectivamente, aunque la idea es que la información se continúe recibiendo en forma de array. Gracias por la aportación

Answer (score 0):

Creo que ya lo tengo:

```
<form method="post">
    0<input type="checkbox" name="campo[0]"/>
    1<input type="checkbox" name="campo[1]"/>
    2<input type="checkbox" name="campo[2]"/>
    <button>Probar</button>
</form>
```

Forzando yo mismo el índice...

¿Se os ocurre alguna otra opción?