# Como enviar todos los checkbox de un formulario

Tags: php, html

Buen día devs, ya googlee con respecto de esto, pero si tengo por ejemplo 5 checkbox y de name tengo esto name=valida[], pero me manda solo los checkbox en on cuando estan checkados, pero necesito tambien los demás que no estan checkados, como puedo realizar esto.

Gracias de antemano

```
<form method="post" action="permissions">
                            @csrf
                            @foreach ($permissions as $p)
                                <tr style="background-color: {{ $p->role_id == 2 ? 'gray' : 'skyblue' }}">
                                <td class="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="role[]" value="{{ $p->role_id }}">
                                    {{ $p->rol }}
                                </td>
                                <td class="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="module[]" value="{{ $p->module_id }}">
                                    {{ $p->modulo }}
                                </td>
                                <td class="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="crear[]" @if($p->crear == 1) checked @endif">
                                </td>
                                <td class="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="leer[]" @if($p->leer == 1) checked @endif>
                                </td>
                                <td class="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="actualizar[]" @if($p->actualizar == 1) checked @endif>
                                </td>
                                <td class="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="eliminar[]" @if($p->eliminar == 1) checked @endif>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            <x-button>Actualizar</x-button>
                        </form>
```

Comment: Aquí le dimos bastantes vueltas a ese tema, espero que te resulte útil: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/461813

Comment: @DavidJP Fijate que así no me funciona, actualicé la pregunta e incluí el código, el problema no es como recibo los datos, sino qué es lo que estoy enviando.

Comment: no soy en experto pero en html no existe esto: "x-button" de donde lo has sacado?

Comment: no me queda claro o no veo una explicacion de si estas intentenado enviar los checkbox como lo pretendes hacer ... a la vista corta veo que intentas algo con "permissions" pero en su lugar deberias ser "/permissions" si mas no me equivoco ...

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover es jetstream, utilizo laravel como framework php, ya realicé algo, solo que lo estoy haciendo con javascript. Gracias

Comment: @MauEspaña hay te dejamos varias respuestas, implementa la que mejor se ajuste a tus necesidades ... te recomiendo descartar lo de javascript

Comment: Gracias @FranciscoNuñezIALover revisaré e intentaré implementar la que se adecue mejor.

Answer (score 2):

Tratas de reinventar la rueda. El comportamiento natural de los campos checkbox es enviar solo los formularios checked. No es necesario enviar los valores faltantes, simplemente los puedes comprobar con un `isset()` para detectar lo que haga falta.
De todas formas, si quieres enviar todas las variables del `checkbox`, puedes usar campos `hidden` para enviar lo que haga falta.

Por otro lado, no tiene sentido usar `array[]` si cada checkbox tiene un nombre de variable distinto. En ese caso envía cada checkbox como variable estándar.

Versión 1: Enviar todos los campos como variable estándar:

```html
    <input type="hidden" name="crear" value="null">
    <input type="checkbox" name="crear" value="True">
    <input type="hidden" name="leer" value="null">
    <input type="checkbox" name="leer" value="True">
    <input type="hidden" name="actualizar" value="null">
    <input type="checkbox" name="actualizar" value="True">
    <input type="hidden" name="eliminar" value="null">
    <input type="checkbox" name="eliminar" value="True">
```

Si seleccionas el campo 2 y 4, tendrás:

```php
array ( 
    // ...
    'crear' => 'null', 
    'leer' => 'True', 
    'actualizar' => 'null', 
    'eliminar' => 'True', 
    // ...
)
```

---

Versión 2: Si, por el contrario decides usar el tipo array, útil en caso de generar (por ejemplo) con información de tablas de una Base de Datos:

```html
    <input type="hidden" name="chkbx[0]" value="null">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbx[0]" value="True">
    <input type="hidden" name="chkbx[1]" value="null">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbx[1]" value="True">
    <input type="hidden" name="chkbx[2]" value="null">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbx[2]" value="True">
    <input type="hidden" name="chkbx[3]" value="null">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbx[3]" value="True">
```

Si seleccionas el campo 2 y 4 tendrás:

```php
array ( 
    // ...
    'chkbx' => array ( 'null', 'True', 'null', 'True'),
    // ...
)
```

Comment: te falto la opcion del javascript como bridge para enviar los datos al backend

Answer (score 0):

los checkbox tienen la particularidad de que solo son enviados aquellos que se han marcado como check.

entonces tienes tres (3) workaround:

1. Decir en tu backend que si la variable no se recibe/ no existe, es por que que por "defecto" no fue marcada.

```
    <?php
    if(!isset($_POST['valida']){
        $_POST['valida'] = false;
    }
```

2. Agregar al html antes del checkbox un campo hidden, con el mismo name, el cual es enviado como sustituto del checkbox:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="actualizar[]" value="false">
    <input type="checkbox" name="actualizar[]" @if($p->actualizar == 1) checked @endif>
```

3. El que menos me gusta, usando algo en javascript que se encargue de leer los campos y mediante ajax envie los datos al backend, ya aqui comprometemos la seguridad del framework.